# caml-light last line not throwing warning

Tags: ocaml, ml, caml-light

I'm playing with the difference between `-` as a unary operator and a binary operator in caml-light.

```
let a b = 
print_int b;
  print_newline();
;;


let c d e  = 
print_int d;
  print_newline();
print_int e;
  print_newline();
;;

a (3 - 4 ) ;
c (9 - 4 )
;;
```

I expect the code to either throw an error (because it gets confused about how many arguments a or c have) or to print:

```
-1
5
```

However, it compiles with no problems (compiler version below) and prints 
-1

Can anyone tell me what happens with the last call?

```
Cobrakai$camlc -v
The Caml Light system, version 0.80
  (standard library from /usr/local/lib/caml-light)
The Caml Light runtime system, version 0.80
The Caml Light compiler, version 0.80
The Caml Light linker, version 0.80
Cobrakai$
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ML, all functions take exactly one argument. A seemingly multi-parameter function is actually a function that takes one argument, and returns another function which takes the remaining arguments.

So `let c d e = ...` is actually syntactic sugar for `let c = function d -> function e -> ...`

And the type of `c` is `int -> int -> unit`, and `->` is right-associative, so it is `int -> (int -> unit)`. So you can see clearly that is a function which takes `int` and returns a function.

When you apply it to multiple arguments like `c 1 2`, function application is left-associative so it is actually `(c 1) 2`, so you can see that `c 1` evaluates to a function which then is applied to `2`.

So, when you give a function "too few arguments", the result is a function. This is a useful and common technique in ML called "**partial application**", which allows you a convenient way to "fix" the first few arguments of a function.

I am not sure how the Caml Light interpreter handles it when the expression you type evaluates to a function. But from what you're saying, it seems to not print anything.

Comment: An interesting variation witch with you might wanna play with : let c = function d -> function e -> print_int d;
  print_newline();
print_int e;
  print_newline();
;; Followed by : let c = function d -> 
print_int d;
  print_newline(); 
function e -> print_int e;
  print_newline();
;;